# golang http server does not accept post large data

Tags: http, go, large-files

At current time try use golang http server and compile it from this code:

```
    package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
}

var mux map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8000",
        MaxHeaderBytes: 30000000,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        Handler:        &myHandler{},
    }

    mux = make(map[string]func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))
    mux["/"] = hello

    server.ListenAndServe()
}

type myHandler struct{}

func (*myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if h, ok := mux[r.URL.String()]; ok {
        h(w, r)
        return
    }

    io.WriteString(w, "My server: "+r.URL.String())
}
```

Runs it and send test data via Apache Bench

```
ab.exe -c 30 -n 1000 -p ESServer.exe -T application/octet-stream http://localhost:8000/
```

It's working excelent with small files but ESServer.exe has size 8Mb and I'm receiving next error "apr_socket_recv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (730054)."

What problem may happens?

Comment: Your first issue is you're using ab, which isn't even http/1.1, so is opening a new connection for every request, which won't help when you're running out of file descriptors or ephemeral ports. Next, your mux isn't safe and will panic under concurrent requests.

Comment: @jimb ab is more than happy to do keepalive with `-k`.

Comment: @hobbs: yes, but it's still http/1.0, and the example here  wasn't using `-k` ;)(plus the go http server can outperform `ab` in these contrived microbenchmarks, so it's testing `ab` as much as it's testing the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading the request body, so each request is going to block once all buffers are filled. You always need to read the request in full or forcibly disconnect the client to avoid the request hanging and consuming resources.

At a minimum, you can

```
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r.Body)
```